# How to select all the rows of a html table from all pages

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a html table for which the below library is applied to get pagination, sorting and searching.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

However there is a requirement to have a search box for each columns. I found a way to do that but it is not able to search the data across all the pages. Below is the javascript

```
<script>
  function filterTable(thisInput, thisIndex) {
    $('table').show();
    var selection = thisInput.value;
    
    var dataset = $('table tbody').find('tr');
    // show all rows first
    dataset.show();
    // filter the rows that should be hidden
    dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
    return $(item).find($("td:nth-child("+thisIndex+")")).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(selection) === -1;
    }).hide();

}
<script>
<body>
.....
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="fname" id="fname" onkeyup="filterTable(this, 1)">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Middle Name" name="mname" id="mname" onkeyup="filterTable(this, 2)">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lname" id="lname" onkeyup="filterTable(this, 3)">
....
</body>
```

Any help here would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Using datatables, use the datatables API, not the HTML / DOM methods.  The "hidden" pages are not hidden - they are not part of the DOM.

Comment: *"have a search box"* - this is built-in to datatables (or at least a datatable plugin).  Look on https://datatables.net

Comment: ```function filterTable(thisInput, thisIndex) {
    var selection = thisInput.value;
    var table = $('table').DataTable();

    table
        .columns(thisIndex)
        .search(selection)
        .draw();
}```

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question (and mark it as the correct one).  Make sure it's an answer, not just some code; answer as if someone else had asked and you need to explain the solution.  Seems like it would help others in the future.